# Selecting a POI on Map using a cluster

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am currently using the Map Sample from Microsoft. This sample creates clusters of pins on the map to save space.

I am finding it difficult to be able to select a POI that is on the map and get the properties of the POI.

There are over 1000, POIs so I need clustering, but the sample is not clear on how to select the POI in question.

Code is below:

```
private async Task LoadPlaceInfoAsync()
    {
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///places.txt");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

        // In the places.txt file, each place is represented by three lines:
        // Place name, latitude, and longitude.
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += 3)
        {
            PlaceInfo place = new PlaceInfo
            {
                Name = lines[i],
                Location = new PlaceLocation(double.Parse(lines[i + 1]), double.Parse(lines[i + 2]))
            };

            places.Add(place);

        }
    }

    private void refreshMapIcons()
    {
        // Erase the old map icons.
        myMap.MapElements.Clear();

        // Create an icon for each cluster.
        foreach (var cluster in GetClustersForZoomLevel(previousZoomLevel))
        {
            MapIcon mapIcon = new MapIcon
            {
                Location = new Geopoint(cluster.Location.Geoposition),
                CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible,
            };

            if (cluster.Places.Count > 1)
            {
                // The cluster represents more than one place. Use a custom marker that shows
                // how many places are represented by this cluster, and place the marker
                // centered at the cluster.
                mapIcon.Image = numberIconReferences[Math.Min(cluster.Places.Count, 9) - 2];
                mapIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            }
            else
            {
                // The cluster represents a single place. Label the cluster with the place name.
                mapIcon.Title = cluster.Places[0].Name;
            }
            myMap.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to select a POI? By clicking/tapping? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, I want to be able to tap and or click on the POI. This is going to be a UWP app, so I will need to do both, but for the moment will concentrate on tapping for Mobiles.

Comment: Hi @Scavenger have you got an idea on how this can be done?